# Package for framed boxes

Tags: boxes, framed, tcolorbox

I saw the following framed box in a [Tex-generated PDF](https://www.sstic.org/media/SSTIC2015/SSTIC-actes/hardware_re_for_software_reversers/SSTIC2015-Article-hardware_re_for_software_reversers-czarny_rigo.pdf) and was wondering what package had been used to make it:

[image]

Does anybody recognize it?

Comment: Tikz is perfectly able to do the job, but it's not the only one.

Comment: Either `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, I would say

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a quick setup with `tcolorbox`, using the `\newtcbtheorem` macro, but it can done with a normal `\newtcolorbox` macro as well. The special title setup requires the `skin` library, which is included using `most` option.

I applied a `\newtcolorbox` approach as well, to show how the options of the boxes can be changed, contrary to `\newtcbtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem{Summary}{\bfseries Summary}{enhanced,drop shadow={black!50!white},
  coltitle=black,
  top=0.3in,
  attach boxed title to top left=
  {xshift=1.5em,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={size=small,colback=pink}
}{summary}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{summary}[1][]{title={\bfseries Summary~\thetcbcounter},enhanced,drop shadow={black!50!white},
  coltitle=black,
  top=0.3in,
  attach boxed title to top left=
  {xshift=1.5em,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={size=small,colback=pink},#1}



\begin{document}

\begin{Summary}{}{firstsummary}
Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end
\end{Summary}

\begin{summary}[boxed title style={colback=yellow},colback=green]
Everything needed to decrypt the drive data is stored on the drive itself. No secret is
present in the enclosure.

$\Rightarrow$ The attacker should be able to brute-force the PIN or extract the encryption key
only in software.
\end{summary}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The colours don't match! (+1)

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, I wanted to exaggerate and to show the configurability of `tcolorbox` stuff

Comment: Ahah don't worry, that was tongue in cheek. :P

Comment: colors don't bother me, but the extra space above the text does.  please make it go away.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The spacings can be controlled by the `top` and `bottom` options -- it's just an example, nothing I would use for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with Tikz. The box is within the frame with a margin of `1mm` on either side.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mybox}[4]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text,text width=\columnwidth-1.2cm, draw, rounded corners, line width=1pt, fill=#3, inner sep=5mm] (big) {\\#4};
        \node[draw, rounded corners, line width=.5pt, fill=#2, anchor=west, xshift=5mm] (small) at (big.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]

\mybox{Summary}{red!40}{red!10}{Everything needed to decrypt the drive data is stored on the drive itself. No secret is
present in the enclosure.}

\mybox{Summary 1}{green!40}{green!10}{This is a very different box... Well, ok, just the colour.}

\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Christian Hupfer's version is a more faithful reproduction of the original, however I do prefer yours from an aesthetic standpoint (spacing, shadows). Plus, tikz ;-)

Comment: @lodhb: The shadows are there, the spacings can be changed and `tcolorbox` is `tikz` ;-)